"Image uploads are limited to 50 megapixels" looks weird for animated GIF
I tried to upload animated GIF with the size less than 2MiB and dimensions 600 х 388, but got unexpected error message:




Image uploads are limited to 50 megapixels; please use a smaller image

It seems that algorithm to calculate the image megapixels works wrong for that case. Additionally there were no such restrictions before, at least I didn't face with that before.

Found the root cause, it's not about file size at all. And already explained by developer in the dupe.

@greg-449 yes it's the same.

@ShadowWizard we should definitely undelete this FR

Sure, I added a vote, but it's pointless: it's like trying to keep water in a bucket having a small hole. The water will just leak again. (i.e. Roomba will nuke it again)

@ShadowWizard at least I will do upvote and maybe futher bounty

@αλεχολυτ it's undeleted now.  fyi Disable roomba on Meta.SE feature requests
